# Show that $\frac{ n^{1/3} }{n-1} > \frac{ (n+1)^{1/3} }{n}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

I am trying to demonstrate that:
$$\frac{ n^{1/3} }{n-1} > \frac{ (n+1)^{1/3} }{n}$$

for $n>0$

I am really struggling. I can get to the point $-2n^3+2n-1>0$ but I am really unsure of how to progress from there.

I know that the answer is that $n>2$ from wolfram-alpha, I am just not sure how to demonstrate it.

Comment: It is certainly not true for $0<n<1$, because then the LHS is negative.

Comment: I think that OP assumes that $n$ is integer.

Answer (score 4):

Let 
$$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt[3]{x+1}}{x}$$
Take logarithms:
$$g(x)=\ln f(x)=\frac13\ln(x+1)-\ln x$$
Now,
$$g'(x)=\frac1{3(x+1)}-\frac1x$$
which is negative for $x\ge 1$. That is, $f$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

Let define us a function $\xi :[1,\infty )\to \mathbb{R} , $ $\xi (v) = (v-1)^{-1} v^{\frac{1}{3} } .$ The derivative $$ \xi ' (v) =(v-1)^{-1} v^{-\frac{2}{3} } \left[ \frac{1}{3} -\frac{v}{v-1}\right]<0$$
and thus $\xi $ is monotone decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, your inequality is equivalent to the following inequality
$$ n^{\frac43}>(n-1)(n+1)^{\frac13} $$
or
$$ n^{4}>(n-1)^3(n+1). $$
Easy calculation shows that
\begin{eqnarray}
n^4-(n-1)^3(n+1)=2n^3-2n+1=2n(n^2-1)+1>0,\forall n>1.
\end{eqnarray}
So
$$ \frac{ n^{1/3} }{n-1} > \frac{ (n+1)^{1/3} }{n}. $$